# How do you change the style of adazzle react data grid?

Tags: reactjs

I want to change the design for the adazzle react data grid, I want to integrate some tailwind ui designs and add some classnames to each columns and rows. But I can't figure out how. If there's someone here who's already done that, a little help would be great. Thank you!

I'm using https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid